# DateTime->format() isn't returning a string

Tags: php, datetime, mysqli

I've been making some code to loop through until a certain amount of data has been retrieved from an API, incrementing the date used by 1 each time. I've encountered an error which I can't seem to fix, where I get the error: `Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string`

As far as I know, the format function on a DateTime object should and does always return a string, but even after formatting it, it says that it isn't. This is my code:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `orders` (`orderReference`,`assignedAocId`,`dropDate`) VALUES(?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `assignedAocId`=VALUES(`assignedAocId`), `dropDate`=VALUES(`dropDate`)");
$stmt->bind_param('sis',$order_reference,$aoc_id,$date);

while(count($aoc_ids) > 0) {
    // $date = date("d/m/Y");
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date->modify("-30 days");

    $aoc_id = $aoc_ids[0];

    $run_count = 0;
    $populated_count = 0;

    while($populated_count < 2 && $run_count < 5) {
        $date = $date->modify("+1 day");
        $formatted_date = $date->format("d/m/Y"); // Keeps looping through and incrementing date but never gets data
        $session_id = generate_session_id($ch);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://live3.maxoptra.com/rest/2/distribution-api/orders/getOrdersWithZone");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "sessionID={$session_id}&date={$formatted_date}&aocID={$aoc_id}");
        if(($xml = new SimpleXMLElement(curl_exec($ch))) !== false) {
            if($xml->error->errorCode != 1016) {
                if (sizeof($xml->OrdersWithZoneResponse->orders) > 0) {
                    foreach ($xml->OrdersWithZoneResponse->orders->order as $order) {
                        $order_reference = (string)$order["referenceNumber"];
                        $stmt->execute(); // Throws the error on this line
                    }
                    $populated_count = $populated_count+1;
                }     
                $run_count = $run_count+1;
            } elseif($xml->error->errorCode == 1016) {
                handle_error("getOrdersWithZone Invocation Limit Reached");
            } else {
                handle_error("getOrdersWithZone Unknown Error Code Returned",$debug_email);
                exit();
            }
        } else {
            handle_error("getOrdersWithZone cURL Failed",$debug_email);
            exit();
        }
    }
    array_shift($aoc_ids);
}
```

Comment: You have a `$date` here `$stmt->bind_param('sis',$order_reference,$aoc_id,$date);`  and in your `while` loop you declare a new `$date`, are they the same?

Comment: @MickaelLeger I can't believe I didn't spot that, so obvious as well... Post this as an answer if you'd like :)

Comment: This was your problem? Glad if it works now !

Comment: @MickaelLeger Yeah that was literally it! I'd changed the way that the date variable was working but forgot that it was still referencing it as if it was in the correct format, I changed it to $formatted_date and now it's fine

Comment: No need to post an anwser I guess if it's a typo mistake and not an actual error :) You can close your question I think !